# django.core.exceptions.ValidationError value must be a decimal number

Tags: python, django

So, I have two different django models, I want to fill one field in one model (that is configured as CharField) with some string, based on a condition, what string is in an other model. I wrote a simple method for that:
[method screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Krz9.png)

```py
    def detect_closing_reason(self):
        if self.recommendation.stoploss is None:
            return 'Non-recognized'
        else:
            return 'Closing by a stoploss'
```

In next method of a class I'm trying to call this method inside of a creating and saving a model instance:[model creating and saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IEY3.png)

```py
    def create_virtual_transaction(self):
        date = self.recommendation.posted_time
        posix_date = datetime.timestamp(date)
        vo = VirtualTransaction.objects.create(start_price=self.recommendation.buy_levels,
                                               start_date=posix_date,
                                               end_price=self.recommendation.sell_levels,
                                               end_date=None,
                                               is_closed=None,
                                               author=self.take_author(),
                                               stock=self.recommendation.stock,
                                               coin=self.recommendation.coin,
                                               closing_reason=self.detect_closing_reason()))
        vo.save()
```

When I run this via django management command, I'm receiving this error:[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcH55.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1554, in to_python
    return decimal.Decimal(value)
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/work/signals/trading_signals/parser/management/commands/add_virtual_transaction.py", line 21, in handle
    pc.create_virtual_transaction()
  File "/home/work/signals/trading_signals/parser/profit_analysis.py", line 57, in create_virtual_transaction
    closing_reason=self.detect_closing_reason())
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 422, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1334, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1278, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1278, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1277, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1218, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1563, in get_db_prep_save
    return connection.ops.adapt_decimalfield_value(self.to_python(value), self.max_digits, self.decimal_places)
  File "/home/work/.local/share/virtualenvs/signals-3Fvtwo2f/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1559, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'[]' value must be a decimal number."]
```

Both fields (first I'm taking from another model in a method on a first screenshot, second I'm trying to save in a DB) configured as CharField:[first field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCUZB.png) [second field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcCqY.png)

```py
class TelegramRecommendation(models.Model):
    channel_name = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    channel_forwarded_name = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    stock = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    coin = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    buy_levels = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    sell_levels = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    posted_time = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
    stoploss = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('channel_forwarded_name', 'posted_time')


class VirtualTransaction(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Recommender, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    coin = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    start_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=8, blank=True, null=True)
    end_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=8, blank=True, null=True)
    is_closed = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    closing_reason = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
```

I had tried to reset migrations and to drop and create a DB (PostgreSQL 11.4), that hadn't helped. [my 0001_initial.py migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39r3Y.png)

```py
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='TelegramRecommendation',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('channel_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2000)),
                ('channel_forwarded_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2000)),
                ('stock', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2000)),
                ('coin', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2000)),
                ('message', models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)),
                ('buy_levels', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2000)),
                ('sell_levels', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2000)),
                ('posted_time', models.DateTimeField(default=None)),
                ('stoploss', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2000)),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ('channel_forwarded_name', 'posted_time'),
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='VirtualTransaction',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('stock', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2000)),
                ('coin', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2000)),
                ('start_date', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2000)),
                ('end_date', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2000)),
                ('start_price', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=8, max_digits=16)),
                ('end_price', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=8, max_digits=16)),
                ('is_closed', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2000)),
                ('closing_reason', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2000)),
                ('author', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='parser.Recommender')),
```

And my \d+ tablename result from a psql [table information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSjhD.png)

I had found some similar question here, but nothing had helped, I had tried: reset migrations, cast a string as a Decimal built-in instance

I don't have so much expirience in django and I could make a silly mistake, but I spent troubleshooting around 12 hours already, so I decided to write a question here.

Comment: It is much easier for people to review your code if you copy and paste it into your question instead of screenshot it.

Comment: Please provide code in lieu of snap shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by some of the 2 `DecimalField` you have in the model `VirtualTransaction` (`start_price` or `end_price`).
It only looks like the error is in `self.detect_closing_reason()` because that is the last parameter to `.objects.create()`; the error actually happens because one of the `DecimalField`s

Most likely, the contents of one of the `CharField`s `self.recommendation.buy_levels` or `self.recommendation.sell_levels` cannot be converted to a `Decimal` instance.

Also, after using the method `.objects.create()` you don't need to call `.save()` on the returned object if you don't modify anything after the `.objects.create()` call.

To discover the error easier, I recommend to change your code to this:

```
def create_virtual_transaction(self):
    date = self.recommendation.posted_time
    posix_date = datetime.timestamp(date)

    vo = VirtualTransaction()
    vo.start_price = self.recommendation.buy_levels
    vo.start_date = posix_date
    vo.end_price = self.recommendation.sell_levels
    vo.end_date = None
    vo.is_closed = None
    vo.author = self.take_author()
    vo.stock = self.recommendation.stock
    vo.coin = self.recommendation.coin
    vo.closing_reason = self.detect_closing_reason()
    vo.full_clean()
    vo.save()
```

Note the call to `vo.full_clean()`; this line will raise a much more specific error message, indicating the field that causes the error.